# how to save client machine time if the server is in different location

Tags: java, web-services, date, datetime

I have to save the date and time of booking in the database after the successful booking. I have tried like the following

```
if(bookingSuccess){
DateTime bookingDate = new DateTime ();
storeDate(bookingDate );
} 


storeDate(DateTime date){

....

}
```

but it wont work if the server is in one location and the client is in another location. Please suggest any solution for this.

Comment: So you have a web-application regular client-server architecture? And moreover what do you mean by it does not work, do you get an exception is date to late, to early, isnt saved at all ...etc. SPECIFY PLEASE

Comment: yes i have. the problem is it is saving the server time instead of client time.

Comment: than you have your answer with sumit jain. use client site script to get the time and than sent it to the server. It should be obvious, that the server doesnt calculate the client time.

Comment: Save the time in UTC then have the client convert the time to local time.

Comment: to be simple and specific ... i have to get client machine time and store that in my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run java script code on client side to get current time

```
var d = new Date();
```

while saving the booking entries , you can get the current time of user machine and save it in a variable. If booking is successful then save that time.

steps:

- fetch booking details and current time of client
- save booking
- when booking is successful then save client time if server and client are on different locations

Comment: Do not recommend relying on the client's clock for this.  The client could be wrong by minutes, hours, or even years.  Use the server's clock which you know is correct.

Comment: yes your are right, we should not rely on client's machine. What we can do is get the time zone of client and then calculate the time on server... right?

Comment: Right. Like [mike](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1286621/mike) already said, store the time of events in UTC time zone on the server.  This way you can easily sort the time of all events.  Only when code is showing a time to the user, then it should convert the time to the user's own time zone.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Relational Database(Mysql,Oracle,Postgress,Sqlite,etc.) and Java, 
Do the following
1) You can have a field for booked_time with data_type TIMESTAMP in your booking_details table 
2) If you are using ORM tool like JPA,Hibernate
    i)  transaction.begin()
    ii) insert booking details into db, Date must be

```
       Date bookingDate=new Date();

iii) transaction.commit();
iV) If error transaction.rollback();
```

3) If you are not using ORM
   Insert into db directlu